# Add drop shadow in 3d image using cloudinary

Tags: 3d, shapes, cloudinary, dropshadow

I want results like the below screenshot [image]

I tried to like this.
https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_800,h_667,c_fill/w_800,h_667,c_fill,l_flower,o_60,bo_1px_solid_rgb:FFFFFF/w_15,h_667,c_crop,g_east/e_distort:0:10:15:0:15:667:0:662/x_-15,g_west,fl_layer_apply/e_distort:0:0:815:15:815:652:0:667/co_black,e_shadow:10,x_-20,y_0/c_pad/sample.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can upload a shadow shape to your account and use `u_undelyname`.

I believe this is what you're looking for:
https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/w_800,h_667,c_fill/w_800,h_667,c_fill,l_flower,o_60/w_15,h_667,c_crop,g_east/e_distort:0:10:15:0:15:667:0:662/x_-15,g_west,fl_layer_apply/e_distort:0:0:815:15:815:652:0:667/w_900,h_547,x_-80,y_80,u_shadow_stackoverflow,fl_layer_apply/sample.jpg

If you like the shadow shape that that I used - here is a link you can download it from: https://freepikpsd.com/shadow-png-pic-shadow-png/239091/

And here are two useful guides for making 3d images using Cloudinary:

1. Convert an Image to a 3D Canvas With Cloudinary: https://cloudinary.com/blog/turning_a_flat_image_into_a_three_dimensional_canvas_with_cloudinary
2. How To Distort Images Dynamically to Fit your Graphic Design: https://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_dynamically_distort_images_to_fit_your_graphic_design#how_to_distort_images_in_the_cloud